# What is the best way to implement storage for a hit counter in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

I am creating a hit counter which serves to keep track of how many people accessed a particular page. The table which holds this information contains the page_id, ip_address, and timestamp (when the IP address accessed the page).

The "issue" I'm having is which is the best way to save this information. If I store it every time a user accesses the page it affects the website performance as well as problems may rise in the saving process. I was hoping of maybe using the `Application_End` in the `Global.asax` file to add the records in the counter table. But how can I save such records? Do I make use of an `Application` variable? If yes, how?

Comment: Do you save the stats to an SQL Server database? some other database? Or is it meant to be only in memory and deleted after startup or so?

Comment: Ye, it is saved in a SQL Server db.

Comment: have you considered google analytics? May not be flexible enough for what you need, but might be worth considering if you haven't already

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
which is the best way to save this information
```

There are three ways that can help to not affect performance of showing the page, and care only about what data you goin to save and keep your way.

### First way

You can use a handler that you call from the page as image, only to write this statistic counter. In this handler you do not use session and for that reason you not even block other pages. And also this is not called from most of the spiders, so you write only real users.

You place the call on the page this way:

```
<img src="keepstats.ashx?Page=CurrentPage.aspx" height="1" width="1" alt="" >
```

and the handler is

```
// 1x1 transparent GIF
private readonly byte[] GifData = {
    0x47, 0x49, 0x46, 0x38, 0x39, 0x61,
    0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x80, 0xff,
    0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00,
    0x00, 0x2c, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
    0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02,
    0x02, 0x44, 0x01, 0x00, 0x3b
};

public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) 
{
    // save here your stat counter

    // send the image
    context.Response.ContentType = "image/gif";
    context.Response.Buffer = false;
    context.Response.OutputStream.Write(GifData, 0, GifData.Length);
}
```

### Second way

To call this function not from code behind but from inside the page at the end like that. The dis-advanced of this case is that the session is locking the page and the page must totally load to allow the next request to proceeds. But is the most easy to made.

```
<body>
... all the page here...


..bottom of the page..
<%
  // you send this part of the page and user all ready see it
  Response.Flush();
  // now you call the function that calculate the statistics
  // the page still show that is loading, but the user all ready see it
  CallTheStatisticSaveFunction();
%>
</body>
```

### third way

I forget one more way, to create a thread to make the work in parallel and in-dependable from the page.

### Last word

In my code I use all of the above tricks, one for statistics, and the second for actions that must be done at the page but may take some more time. I use the thread for actions that must be done before I start render the page, with some tricks that if the thread not end I render what I have.

I will avoid session for knowing if the user all ready see the page for this reason:

1. If the user not use cookie the session is not work, and all spiders not use session
2. If the user start see a lot of pages the session data will be grow.

The `Application_End` is called only ones, when you close iis, or stop your application. The  point that is global and called every time is the `Application_BeginRequest` but there you going to affect performance because is called for every asp.net element and you need to check if its a page, if something else, and this at the first point of the page, you going to have delay there. We search here how to write the statistics at the end, after user see something.

Comment: How would you recommend caching the stats? ie maybe caching hit data and periodically writing to a backend db? Do you have any advise on best practices for this? ie using application variable, or asp.net cache objects?

Comment: @gwynhowell Your question is too general for me. Also because I use multi pool and multi thread system I must have a common place for all calls and this is the database (and not the memory) So I left the database to handle the cache of the data - I just make very good and fast calls to the database. Now in one call of a page, in the cycle of call I use all possible places to hold the data till the cycle ends, including some application variables, but this is not what you ask.

Comment: Interesting. I am considering how to tackle a similar challenge. My approach was to cache stat data at the server but maybe I'm overcomplicating things. Am interested about your comment "I left the database handle the cache of the data" - do you have any further information on this? Thanks

Comment: @gwynhowell well, I can tell you that sql have a great cache, also keep statistics and have a great way to get and save data. Also have a great way to search data - integer and strings. I have made some real tests and sql is always faster. For example if you search for an integer in a loop of 10000 data, the sql use tricks to locate it in few compare and is not running all the data to find it. Dictionary<T> make similar search of data.

Comment: @gwynhowell I say that is better to look how you make faster the communication with the sql server. For example not use linq or any other dao that make all the time compiles at real time. Read and save only the data you need on the SQL. I also use SQL Server to cache part of the render of the page that this is the where I lose time. Anyway, is to general and I think every case is different. Check this page to see if they are fast kappashop.gr we use 300 tables, and there are 70-100 table read on every page.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Aristos I will do some research on sql cache.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options; you can use `Session` object to store hits, so that when the same user (IP address) hits the same page, it won't be saved again.

It's important to remember that this option is relevant if you run in one server (of course there are solutions to a web farm - but I don't think it's your case and it might be wrong to detail them here) and don't have too many unique visitors, because the Session will quickly fill your available memory.

There are other options like using Redis - but for the beginning, filtering repetitive hits by using `Session` is OK for a site with not-very-high load.